# SSPI from Windows XP Mode to Windows 7 SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, windows-xp, sspi

I currently have to maintain some legacy code in Visual Studio 2003 and .NET 1.1.  It uses integrated security to connect to a database.  I am using WinXP mode in Windows 7 for the VS2003 install.  I have the SQL Server 2008 installed on the Windows 7 machine.  However when I try and connect to the SQL Server from VS2003 I always get the could not generate the SSPI context.  The WinXP mode install is connected to the domain and I can access any other resource on the domain (shared folders, SQL servers using SSPI on other machines).  It appears that the only thing I cannot access using SSPI is the SQL server installed on the Win 7 host box from VS2003 inside WinXP mode.  Has anyone else had this issue and can offer a resolution?

Comment: Is the Win7 machine also joined to the domain?

Comment: Check the network configs on the Win7 box.  It could be 1) windows firewall is not permitting TCP traffic (port 1433)  2) SQL Server (by default) does not answer to TCP traffic, only named pipes.  You can use the SQL config panel to allow this (if its installed).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Win7 firewall.  [My Computer, right-click Network, Properties, Windows Firewall [lower-left corner], Advanced Settings, Inbound Rules, right-click, New Rule, Port, Next, TCP + Special local ports: 1433, Next, Allow the connection, Next, Domain (not public, because it is the safest choice for you), Next, Name=SQLServer, Finish].
2. Check SQL Server network config.  [Start, All Programs, Microsoft SQL 2008, Configuration Tools, Sql Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Network Configuration (expand), Protocols for MSSQLSERVER].  Shared Memory will be Enabled.  Make sure TCP/IP is Enabled.   Double-click TCP/IP, under the "IP Addresses" tab, find your IP address, it should start with 192. or 10. make sure it is "Active=Yes" and "Enabled=Yes".

Comment: It's not a firewall issue.  I can access the SQL Sever from the WinXP mode if I use a SQL login (not integrated security) just fine with no issues.  The issue occurs when I try and use integrated security.  It does not seem to want to hit the domain to get the authentication token it needs before it fails.

I checked to ensure that TCP/IP is enabled for SQL server and it is.